# I can't make my app use the navigationOptions from the component file instead of the routes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I defined a `routes.js` file where all the routes from my Drawer navigation are created. This works fine except in one instance. I have one StackNavigator like so:

```
const ChatScreens = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Chat: {
      screen: Chat,
    },
    Transactions: {
      screen: Transactions,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerLeft: (
          <MaterialIcons
            name="chat"
            size={24}
            style={{ color: colors.BLACK, marginLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()} //not working
          />
        ),
      }
    },
    Logout: {
      screen: AuthLoadingScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'card',
    initialRouteName: 'Chat',
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: getDrawerItemIcon('chat'),
    }
  },
);
```

This code, if removed would render a default "< Back" arrow that works just fine. However, I want to use the icon. I tried adding said navigationOptions inside my `Transactions.js` file but they just get ignored. The only way they take effect is by adding this inside my `routes.js` the problem, is that there is no navigation within the said file so, of course, I get the `Can't find variable: navigation` error.

I attempted to change this line to `NavigationActions` but it won't work either if I do `.navigate()` or `.back()`. The truth is that I know the best place for this navigationOptions is within my Transactions file but I can't figure out why it's not working over there.

So either could you a) help me understand why it won't work under Transactions.js or b) help me make the navigation work inside my routes.js for this case?

Just FYI, towards the bottom of my `routes.js` I have my DrawerNavigation created successfully the following way:

```
export default Drawer = createAppContainer(
  createDrawerNavigator({
    Chat:{
      screen: ChatScreens,
    },
    Info:{
      screen: InfoScreens,
    },
    User: {
      screen: UserScreens,
    },
    Feedback: {
      screen: FeedbackScreens,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: <Hidden />
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Chat',
    contentComponent: DrawerContent,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.TURQUOISE,
      itemsContainerStyle: {
        marginVertical: 0,
      },
      iconContainerStyle: {
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `navigation` in navigationOptions, you need to use the method like `navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {}`

For example,

```
class A extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerLeft: (
          <MaterialIcons
            name="chat"
            size={24}
            style={{ color: colors.BLACK, marginLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
          />
        ),
      }
    };
  };

...
```

But you try to use `navigation` not defined.

```
onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()} // navigation is not defined
```